# Using Javascript to submit multiple PDF forms?

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, acrobat

Is it possible to submit multiple PDF forms at once, if they've been filled out separately in different files? It would have to be done from within a PDF file, and be as simple as clicking a button since it will be for end users.

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for this. The `<input type="file" />` lets you select multiple files with the `multiple="multiple"` attribute.

Comment: I guess I should have clarified that can a user of multiple PDF forms that they've downloaded onto their computer from a website click a button inside one of the forms and submit data from all of the other separate PDF forms that they've also filled out ? Is that something that can actually be done?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but without more details, I can't provide a specific answer. First, all of the "slave" PDF files will need to have their disclosed property set to "true". You will also need to install a folder level script that allows you to get an array of the active documents because the function is subject to security restrictions. Then you can call doc.sibmitForm() from the master to cause each document to submit itself.

Comment: What other details do you need? And what you describe definitely sounds like it might work but is it possible for an end user to just hit a submit button or something similar that would active the whole process?

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate on this? It seemed like a possible solution.

Comment: I'm happy to elaborate. Can you move this to a discussion?

Comment: Sorry to sound very ignorant but – not sure what you mean. How do I move it to a discussion? I'm still a relatively new StackExchanger.

Comment: Hi Joe - sorry if I'm nagging but just interested in hearing what you have to say. Just not sure how to "move this to a discussion" as you said.

Comment: Please join the chat room for Acrobat JavaScript. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147997/javascript-for-acrobat

Comment: I guess I can't because I don't have a reputation of 20 here?